# How much should you refine a question before opening a new question?

Tags: discussion

When editing your own question, sometimes the initial problem is something completely different to what you expected, and the original question becomes obsolete. How far do you think you should edit and refine a question before simply opening a new one?

Recent example:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/363784
- [Why does RAID5 with an odd number of data disks have poor write performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/365903)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion (as stated in the comments on the RAID-specific question you cite) is that if the existing comments and/or answers (if any) on your question would no longer make sense in the context of the modified question, then you should open a new question.  Of course, if your old question has no continuing value, then you should also close your old one (if possible) to keep things tidy.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't been able to close your own questions (on your own, you can still vote to close) for quite a while now, without moderator intervention.

Comment: Hmm, darn... I don't think I've ever even tried to close my own question.  At any rate, if you really need to close your own question, you can poke-a-mod and have them do it -- it's what they're there for, after all, to keep the site clean.

Comment: I'd generally agree with what @womble said -- As long as the edit doesn't completely warp the question so that valid answers to the original are no longer valid, edit away to make your question better.  If you find that your original question isn't the real problem, ask a new one (and if you think your original question was really that awful go ahead and delete it, or flag it.  (I would go so far as to say you may want to delete your original question if you're sure it's *not* Samba's fault that your performance is suck-tastic)

Answer (score 2):

Stackexchange sites are Question and Answer sites.

People put up answers.  if the answers no longer relate to the question at hand because the author of the question has changed it then this is unhelpful.

IMHO, Put up a new question for a new question so that others who come and read this in future will have something meaningful to read.

Comment: Did you look at the questions? The original had no answers before the follow up was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example, I believe that the original should have been edited. The first question was basically "help me with my performance problem". The first question got no answers, but got some comments that might be pointing you in another direction. Whether or not those are right is another matter.

That said, it seems that you've come to the conclusion on your own that the problem is *not* Samba, so your initial question was asked on a false assumption. Because of that, the original question, as asked, holds no practical value. Instead of abandoning it, I feel that it should be edited to more accurately reflect the situation at hand, since it's about the same underlying performance issue.