# Question modified into new question after being answered

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Earlier I answered [this (now deleted) question](https://serverfault.com/questions/981641/setup-exim4-to-send-mails-from-web-application) about SMTP configuration. After I answered it, the OP changed the question completely, including my suggested changes and posted the next problem that arose after my suggested solution.

I told the OP so in comments, with the intention of pointing them towards creating a new question with the new problem, because the new wording of the question rendered my answer completely invalid (keeping in line with [this Q/A](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3073/how-much-should-you-refine-a-question-before-opening-a-new-question)).

Since the OP has been on SF for 8 years and had already earned a solid amount of reputation I assumed that he knows how this site works, but the OP argued that it is still the same topic. Since the OP seemed to be determined to stay on that position I deleted my (now invalid) answer.

After that the OP decided to delete the whole question.

Is there anything I could have done differently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you were right to think that he should have posted a new question. Indeed, if he had not deleted it, I would have rolled back his edit and advised him to post his new problem separately.

I don't think you were right to assume he knows how the site works, even after eight years. Since he doesn't have very much reputation, it could be that he doesn't actually spend a lot of time here. He does, however, spend quite a bit of time at Stack Overflow, and perhaps he knows how that site works. As far as I know, they also would not accept this sort of situation and would expect separate questions. I could be wrong about that, though.

Based on the user's further activity, though, I suspect he deleted the question because he thought he figured out his new issue himself, and decided to move on.  Then realized he hasn't, and posted a new question. When you see the new question, you'll have to decide for yourself whether to bother putting in any effort answering it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that SO handles this issue the same. I used to spend a LOT of time there.

Comment: So, should I just have asked the OP more directly to ask a new question with his current problem?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That might have helped, though I suspect he would have just ignored you as well.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Just a note, the member got some self-deleted questions, like more than 10 (but mostly all without answer(s)), but the fact he got a lot of reputation make the question ban far away to act sadly. I will keep that in mind if I see back the user self-delete questions, especially if answer are wrote, as it can be seen as content destruction.